Identity - Django View that accepts both Auth and Non-Auth users
I have integrated Azure AD with Django using identity[django] package (docs).
It provides a @login_required decorator that is used to restrict a view only for AD authenticated users. The view function decorated should accept an additional parameter context which contains the AD info.
I have written a custom decorator that creates a Django User object using the AD info provided by identity context.
def custom_login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    @settings.AUTH.login_required
    def wrapped(request, context=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if context:
            request.user = get_ad_synced_user(context)
        return f(request, context=context, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@custom_login_required
def home(request, *, context):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

<html>
  <body>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}!</p>
    {% endif %}
  </body>
</html>

However, I want to create a view that accepts both authenticated and non-authenticated users. If the user is not authenticated, it should display a link to login page, and if the user is authenticated, then it should display private links.
Using the Django User object, I can have access to request.user.is_authenticated, but since identity creates a separate object context (which gets AD info only when decorated with @login_required), I'm not sure how I can set request.user for the current request from the previous request.

can you please share your full code what you've tried
